# How to reverse the jsf components position on the screen

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu and a precise input set beside a button with a small arrow to flip them on the page, leave the input above and below the selectOneMenu. My application is JavaEE, JSF and use Primefaces.Alguém can give me an example? I searched on google but not found.

Comment: So, you have something like that:
SelectOneMenu ARROW
Input
After you press the arrow you want it to be like this:
Input ARROW
SelectOneMenu
Thats it?

Comment: as an ugly solution, you can have a boolean variable in your backing bean, altered by the button, deciding the input will be above or below. then you can duplicate the input component with almost the same code, only different id's and opposite `rendered` values. if flag is true, one input will be rendered; if false, the other input will...